# How to find google maps Polylines intersections?

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-maps, polyline

I am trying to program some sort of google maps but using only natural hiking paths. My paths are gpx turned into google maps polylines.

Is there any "computationally cheap" way to find the intersections of said polylines? I am working with thousands of routes so iterating point by point is not an option :D

In this link I will show you a map similar to the one I am working with. As you can see we have no clean intersections, and a lot of points to work with.
http://senders.feec.cat/

Comment: If you try to put in some working code or show what you have attempted so far, you may have a better possibility of getting answers

Answer (score 0):

If you read your polylines into `geopandas` you can use the various `intersects` functions to achieve your task.

Comment: It's a  good idea, but since all the information comes from gpx files, there's not a physical intersection on the data. That means, that what we as humans see as an intersection between 2 lines, the computer only sees 4 points close to each other being part of 2 different polylines. Basically, we dont have a common point...

Comment: @Xebind Can you not just represent the lines in a graph format (node-link) and then locate nodes of different categories (lines) within a known radius of each other in that case? Or simpler still just convert them into polygons by adding and subtracting a small lateral distance from each point on and then calculate the overlap.

Comment: Yes, the graph format would be the easier way to program directions with the routes, considering intersections as nodes and paths as actions, but I would like to get the intersections via code, not manually. I edited the main message showing a map with what I am working with. The idea is to be able to use this routes as google maps uses roads to give you directions.